# popup dialog box in wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, dialog, popup

Inside a page in the wordpress, I would like the user click on a text link and then a popup dialog box show up with some pre-entered text, around 50 words. something like those windows but need the user click on the link before show up.

How to do it html? or any wordpress plugin let me do that?

Thanks,

Comment: Search for '[wordpress lightbox](https://www.google.ca/search?q=lightbox+wordpress)' if you want to just install a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

using javascript, you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("hello this is 50 words")
</script>
```

but you have to include that in ur header.

give your text link an ID like

```
<a href="http://gothislink.com" id="textid">click me</a>
```

then in the script, u can use jQuery

```
$('#textid').click(function(){
    alert("lalala");
});
```

See this fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/m74Yu/

Download [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) into your diectory/static and include the script in the html header

```
<script src="static/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

or just insert this without downloading anything

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: but how can I tie it to the text or button?

Comment: please see the fiddle example above :) vote up if this is useful :)

Comment: tried but not working, do i have put anything more in the page to call those?

Comment: hmm how do u access your html script for your wordpress? CTRL+F header may help. if you can't find it, make one. `<html><header> ...</header><body>... </body></html>`